# testng how to dynamically set groups from Factory?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, factory

Before I setup a test class like the code below:
1. the Factory and test Dataprovider both used excel as the dataprovider.
2. In the Factory dataprovider table, it has a list of url
3. Each time, it will find one of the url in the factory dataprovider table, and run the test in each test methods..

```
public class Test {
    WebDriver driver;
    private String hostName;
    private String url;


    @Factory(dataProvider = "xxxx global variables", dataProviderClass = xxxx.class)
    public GetVariables(String hostName, String url) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.url = url;

    }

    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void start(String browser) throws Exception {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    @Test(priority = 10, dataProvider = "dataprovider Test A", dataProviderClass = xxx.class)
    public void TestA(Variable1,
            Variable2,Variable3) throws Exception {
        some test here...

    }

    @Test(priority = 20, dataProvider = "dataprovider Test B", dataProviderClass = xxx.class)
    public void TestB(Variable1,
            Variable2,Variable3)
            throws Exception {
        some test here...
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Now I want to dynamically assign different group for each test for different url. I am thinking add a variable 'flag' in the @Factory dataprovider:

```
@Factory(dataProvider = "xxxx global variables", dataProviderClass = xxxx.class)
public GetVariables(String hostName, String url, String flag) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
    this.url = url;
    this.flag = flag;
}

That when flag.equals("A"), it will only run test cases in test groups={"A"}.
When flag.equals("B"), it will only run test cases in test groups ={"B"},
When flag.equals("A,B"), it will only run test cases in test groups ={"A","B"}
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG groups provides "flexibility in how you partition your tests" but it isn't for conditional test sets. For that you simply use plain old Java.

You can use inheritance or composition (I recommend the latter, see *Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance* from [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)).

Either way the general idea is the same: use a [`Factory`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Factory.html) to create your test class instances dynamically creating the appropriate class type with the appropriate test annotations and/or methods that you want to run.

Examples:

1. Inheritance

   ```java
   import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class DemoTest {
       @Factory
       public static Object[] createTests() {
           return new Object[]{
                   new FlavorATest(),
                   new FlavorBTest(),
                   new FlavorABTest()
           };
       }

       /**
        * Base test class with code for both A-tests and B-tests.
        *
        * Note that none of these test methods are annotated as tests so that
        * subclasses may pick which ones to annotate.
        */
       public static abstract class BaseTest {
           protected void testA() {
               // test something specific to flavor A
           }

           protected void testB() {
               // test something specific to flavor B
           }
       }

       // extend base but only annotate A-tests
       public static class FlavorATest extends BaseTest {
           @Test
           @Override
           public void testA() {
               super.testA();
           }
       }

       // extend base but only annotate B-tests
       public static class FlavorBTest extends BaseTest {
           @Test
           @Override
           public void testB() {
               super.testB();
           }
       }

       // extend base and annotate both A-tests and B-tests
       public static class FlavorABTest extends BaseTest {
           @Test
           @Override
           public void testA() {
               super.testA();
           }

           @Test
           @Override
           public void testB() {
               super.testB();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Composition

   ```java
   import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class DemoTest {
       @Factory
       public static Object[] createTests() {
           return new Object[]{
                   new FlavorATest(),
                   new FlavorBTest(),
                   new FlavorABTest()
           };
       }

       private static void testA() {
           // test something specific to flavor A
       }

       private static void testB() {
           // test something specific to flavor B
       }

       // only create A-test methods and delegate to shared code above
       public static class FlavorATest {
           @Test
           public void testA() {
               DemoTest.testA();
           }
       }

       // only create B-test methods and delegate to shared code above
       public static class FlavorBTest {
           @Test
           public void testB() {
               DemoTest.testB();
           }
       }

       // create A-test and B-test methods and delegate to shared code above
       public static class FlavorABTest {
           @Test
           public void testA() {
               DemoTest.testA();
           }

           @Test
           public void testB() {
               DemoTest.testB();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Your factory methods won't be as simple as you'll need to use your "flag" from your test data to switch off of and create instances of the appropriate test classes.